# Type error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list while adding <eos>

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I am trying to do this for encoder but I am getting type error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list.

```
 input_sentences = []
output_sentences = []
output_sentences_inputs = []

count = 0
for line in open(r'fre.txt', encoding="utf-8"):
    count += 1

    if count > NUM_SENTENCES:
        break

    if '\t' not in line:
        continue

    input_sentence= line.rstrip().split('\t')
    output = line.rstrip().split('\t')

    output_sentence = output + ' <eos>'
    output_sentence_input = '<sos> ' + output
```

I don't know what to do. Kindly help me.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post a [mre] and the details of the error, i.e. the stack trace and what line of your code it indicates.

Comment: However, from what you've posted I can see that `output` is a list, but you are trying to use it like a string. That's the likely cause of the exception you refer to.

Comment: `output` is a list. First you have to convert in into a string like `''.join(output)` and then you will be able to concat it with another string `output_sentence = ''.join(output) + ' <eos>'`.

Comment: thank you, your solution help with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies here:

```
output_sentence = output + ' <eos>'
output_sentence_input = '<sos> ' + output
```

When you used split on your output

```
output = line.rstrip().split('\t')
```

You create a list.
This is how python sees such a function

```
line = "hello my name is "

output = line.split('\t')

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['hello my name is ']
```

So when you put output + "", you are concatenating  a list (output) and a string ("eos").
You can't do that.
You can concatenate a string and a string, or a list and a list, but not a list and a string.